# How to import C4D Animations Into Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, cinema-4d

The following post is a collection of my replies on Unity Forums.

> Is anyone familiar with any possible ways to import a c4d animation with emitter/metaball or basically anything besides rigged bones into Unity? Recently tried to import a flame-looking animation based on EJ Hassenfratz's tutorial http://www.eyedesyn.com/2015/05/07/creating-2d-cartoon-fire-effects-in-cinema-4d/. I used NitroBake to bake my animation to keyframes and then exported as .fbx, however when I imported it into Unity no animation would show. I was told there are ways to overcome such problems using some Unity extensions but the person was really busy so I thought I should ask here on Unity forums.
>
> Edit: I should mention that I have imported bone animations before or even simple rotation/position/scale keyframed animations. Also if anyone wants to test how to import I could share the c4d project.

A person suggested MegaFiers Unity Extension (MegaCache to be more accurate)

My following 2 responses:

> I might go fuc*ing crazy trying to import an animation but I'm positive that I'm gonna at least manage to do it. Felt the need to update this thread in case someone else is searching around. C4d doesn't support .pc2 or .mdd file formats. There's a mdd writer and mdd reader over at animationsnippets.com. Sadly it's not compatible with C4d r16. Sometime tomorrow I'll have r13 installed on my PC and test if the mdd writer works there. Assuming it's working I'm gonna give MegaFiers - MegaCache a go to see if it works.
>
> If someone else is importing his animations differently please reply to this topic.

And

> Update: Installed r13, still mddwriter doesn't show up. Seriously why does MegaFiers mention (in a YouTube video) "We added .mdd file format to support c4d" when there's no freaking native export of that file format and no god damn plugin works. For real no word can describe my rage right now. It's been 5-6 years since people started complaining about PLA animations and Unity hasn't done a single update on that area and I doubt they will since there's just one annoying person demanding this. Pfff hopefully someone will know something more. Don't bother mentioning that I could create a custom script on c4d or unity, if I had that kind of knowledge I wouldn't be whining here.

EDIT:
Solved it by my own, visit Unity forums if you're interested to know how. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-how-to-import-c4d-animations-into-unity.339073/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by my own, visit Unity forums if you're interested to know how. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-how-to-import-c4d-animations-into-unity.339073/